# Does Windows keep list of dependencies for installed programs and framework

Tags: windows, visual-c++, redistributable

I did a major cleanup on my Windows lately, removing old software which saw little use. Some of them may or may have not installed their own Visual C++ redistribution. I know removing the redists doesn't seem to make sense, but just in case I still want to remove it, is there a way to check for which program depends on certain redist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not, there is the expectation that applications clean up after themselves.  Unfortunatly this is not the typical action for installataions.

Comment: Application cannot clean up i.e. remove the redist without breaking other programs which rely on the redist. Therefore, a dependency tree is needed to check whether it's safe for uninstaller to remove a redist. The question is: does Windows installed-programs manager have it?

Comment: @syockit- Windows does not do this as I stated.  I recall in XP there used to be warnings about uninstalling items that resided in c:\Program Files\Common Files (may exist in Vista/7 but I don't recall coming across them), but Windows doesn't actually know if its used or not.

Comment: Well, I removed the whole .NET 4 framework, which Visual Studio 2010 Express requires, and it didn't prompt me to uninstall Visual Studio. But .NET itself had to be uninstalled in certain steps i.e. I couldn't remove the multi platform targeting before some other .NET parts. So maybe it is there for some programs, but mostly it is not there.